# when drawing a filled circle, gnuplot gives different output between x11 terminal and latex terminal, why?

Tags: latex, gnuplot

I switched from tikz to gnuplot for drawing math diagrams recently. I find them very different.

I want to draw a circle, so I created a .gpi file:

```
set terminal latex
set out 'gp.tex'
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [-5:5]
set object 1 circle at 0,0 size char 1 fillcolor rgb "black" fillstyle solid
plot NaN
set out
set terminal x11
plot NaN
```

And I loaded it in gnuplot.

The circle in `x11` terminal is filled, as expected:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiHKA.png

But the one compiled from `gp.tex` is a hollow circle:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOCC0.png

Why? How can I produce a filled circle in the tex file as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `latex` terminal is very old and doesn't support filled circles. You should use one of the other LaTeX-related terminals like `epslatex`, `cairolatex` or `tikz` which support filled circles.

See the output of the `test` command to see which features are supported by a terminal. For filled circles, filled polygons must be supported. For `latex` you get:

[image: Output of <code>set terminal latex; test</code>]